# MySQL Closure table: Tree rendering when using GUID instead of auto-increment

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, closures, hierarchical

I’ve implemented a closure table system in MySQL for a hierarchy group list.

The groups are in table company_groups with columns ID and Name
The closure table is company_groups_treepaths:

```
CREATE TABLE `company_groups` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL default '',
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `company_groups_treepaths` (
  `ParentID` char(36) NOT NULL default '',
  `ChildID` char(36) NOT NULL default '',
  `PathLength` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ParentID`,`ChildID`),
  KEY `PathLength` (`PathLength`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And then I am trying to get a tree structure out of it. The problem is that most of the solutions I find is using group_concat on the group id, assuming it’s an INT and auto_increment.

However, I use GUID which makes it harder. I’ve looked through the other examples here, but can’t really get a hang of it.

For example, this query retrieves the right groups, but the wrong tree:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.`ChildID`, p.ParentID, d.name, CONCAT(REPEAT('-', p.`PathLength`), d.`name`) as path, p.`PathLength` as depth
        FROM 
            `company_groups` AS d
        JOIN `company_groups_treepaths` AS p ON d.`id` = p.`ChildID`
        JOIN `company_groups_treepaths` AS crumbs ON crumbs.`ChildID` = p.`ChildID`

        WHERE 
            p.`ParentID` = 'aa420c70-7050-11e2-b75d-672efc30777e'
          GROUP BY d.id

ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(crumbs.`PathLength`)
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/474d4/2

The correct order for that query should be (fetching all children of Swedbank):

Swedbank (aa420c70-7050-11e2-b75d-672efc30777e)

- hejsan (44b2b680-7f44-11e2-b04d-918fe8c8d065)
- Östergötland (aa420970-7050-11e2-893a-7f63b55a76db)
- - Regional1 (a6adc800-7050-11e2-9db0-ad8ff41db08c)
- - - asd (56fd15a0-7f44-11e2-b10f-55240ef76c28)
- - - hejsan3 (fc14c320-7f44-11e2-a2bb-ed51f02fd80f)
- - Under öster (bb6b93a0-80ea-11e2-be1d-fd97d33aad97)
- Småland (ae5dc150-7050-11e2-9b11-c96b3591816c)
- - asdasd (534e3f00-80df-11e2-b92e-fd29e414f3fd)
- - asd (6e640160-80de-11e2-8c41-d135d36c28db)
- hejsan2 (d95a7060-80be-11e2-8179-0b9231964800)

Anyone got any good ideas for tree listing, using GUID?

The function itself won't be called very very often, so I'm fairly open for sub-query suggestions as well if it's necessary to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted to trying out the basics, following outlines found on http://karwin.blogspot.se/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html

This is the query that eventually worked:

```
select group_concat(n.name order by a.PathLength desc separator ' -> ') as fullpath, CONCAT(REPEAT('-', d.`PathLength`), cg.`name`) as path, d.ChildID as group_id, d.PathLength as depth, cg.name
            from company_groups_treepaths d
            join company_groups_treepaths a on (a.ChildID = d.ChildID)
            join company_groups n on (n.id = a.ParentId)
            join company_groups cg on (cg.id = d.ChildID)

            where d.ParentID = 'aa420c70-7050-11e2-b75d-672efc30777e' and cg.deleted = 0 
            group by d.ChildID
            order by fullpath
```